# PowerEdge Servers - Is the HotSwap Caddy Required?

Tags: hard-drive, dell-poweredge, hardware

I have a: PowerEdge 2970 Server
Currently has just 1  160GB 7.2K RPM Serial ATA 3Gbps 3.5-in HotPlug Hard Drive

I need to add 1-2 more hardrives.
I found this one:
http://www.xbyte.com/ProductDesc.aspx?code=CAT_1274_25

however I do not plan on ever removing these, so I feel like I'm paying for a "hot swap" feature I'll do not need.

My question is: Do I need this?
Will another drive, like this one still fit ok?
http://www.tigerdirect.com/applications/SearchTools/item-details.asp?EdpNo=5239129&CatId=4357

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the drive tray. You can't install the drive in the server without a tray. The actual drive itself is immaterial (more or less) but you need a drive tray to put it in.

Comment: Hello, so I can buy an server grade hard drive, put it in a tray like this: http://bit.ly/kVwBdH and it will work?

Comment: If it's the correct tray for the drive and server, then yes.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, there is no other way to mount the drive than the caddy, whether or not you ever plan on hot-swapping it doesn't matter.

This is one of those situations where just buying the correct parts is the only option, IMO.

Comment: In other words, OP: Stop Being Cheap. It'll only come back to bite you in the arse.

Comment: Wrong, it's enterprise grade. "Data centers, web service providers, and commercial grade surveillance systems." 
See: http://www.wdc.com/en/products/internal/enterprise/

Answer (score 1):

The drives will fit, but the caddies are the mounts for the server. Without them, the drives how nothing holding them in place.